# Forcing overrides when configuring a compile (e.g. CXXFLAGS, etc.)

Tags: compiling, configure, transmission

I wonder how one could force, for some real example:

- `CFLAGS='-O2 -march=native'`
- `CXXFLAGS='-O2 -march=native'`
- `CC='gcc-10'`
- `CPP='gcc-10 -E'`
- `CXX='g++-10'`

when running the `configure` script in my case for Transmission 3.00 BitTorrent client?

Editing the `configure` file does seem a bit tricky and more importantly not universally usable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documented way to override variables when running `configure` is to specify their values as arguments to `configure`, as explained by `./configure --help`:

```
`configure' configures transmission 3.00 to adapt to many kinds of systems.

Usage: ./configure [OPTION]... [VAR=VALUE]...

To assign environment variables (e.g., CC, CFLAGS...), specify them as
VAR=VALUE.  See below for descriptions of some of the useful variables.
```

In your case,

```
./configure --disable-cli --disable-mac --disable-daemon --enable-utp --with-gtk --with-crypto=openssl CFLAGS='-O2 -march=native' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -march=native' CC=gcc-10 CPP='gcc-10 -E' CXX=g++-10
```

[`configure` takes environment variables into account by default](https://autotools.io/autoconf/arguments.html#autoconf.adding-options.ac_arg_var), which is why [setting them also works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/654154/86440). In both cases, the values set are preserved in `config.status` (if the variables are marked as “precious”) and taken into account with `config.status --recheck`. The Autoconf documentation [recommends specifying variables as arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Defining-Variables.html#Defining-Variables) rather than relying on the environment.

Answer (score 0):

What has worked (but is not the official approach), in my case of Transmission 3.00, was to simply add those in front of `./configure` like so, I will not alter my command and place it in full:

```
CFLAGS='-O2 -march=native' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -march=native' CC='gcc-10' CPP='gcc-10 -E' CXX='g++-10' ./configure --disable-cli --disable-mac --disable-daemon --enable-utp --with-gtk --with-crypto=openssl
```