# How to put multiple -I, -L and -l flags in ./configure?

Tags: compiling, make, configure, automake, autoconf

I am trying to build using `./configure`.

I have

1. Three include directories

   ```
   -I/path1/include
   -I/path2/include
   -I/path3/include
   ```
2. Two link directories

   ```
   -L/path1/lib
   -L/path2/lib
   ```
3. Two `-l` flag options

   ```
   -ltensorflow
   -lasan
   ```
4. Two compile flags

   ```
   -O3
   -g
   ```

How can I put all these flags effectively as options in `./configure`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The canonical way to do this is to provide values for [various variables](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/html_node/Preset-Output-Variables.html) in the `./configure` invocation:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS="-I/path1/include -I/path2/include -I/path3/include" \
            CFLAGS="-O3 -g" \
            LDFLAGS="-L/path1/lib -L/path2/lib" \
            LIBS="-ltensorflow -lasan"
```

If the C++ compiler is used, specify `CXXFLAGS` instead of (or in addition to) `CFLAGS`.

These variables can also be set in the environment, but [recommended practice is to specify them as command-line arguments](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/html_node/Defining-Variables.html) so that their values will be stored for re-use. See [Forcing overrides when configuring a compile (e.g. CXXFLAGS, etc.)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/654153/86440) for details.

Note that in most cases it would be unusual to specify that many paths as flags; instead, I would expect to find `--with` options to tell the `configure` script where to find various dependencies. For example, `--with-tensorflow=/path/to/tensorflow` which would then result in the appropriate `-I` and `-L` flags being set. Run

```
./configure --help
```

to see what options are available.

Comment: I do have a small doubt, does the order in which I put the flags have to be maintained or can I put it in any order, like LIBS first and then LDFLAGS?

Comment: The order doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 3):

```
export CFLAGS="-I/path1/include -I/path2/include -I/path3/include -O3 -g"
export CXXFLAGS=$CFLAGS
export LDFLAGS="-L/path1/lib -L/path2/lib -ltensorflow -lasan"
./configure && make
```