# Recommended way to pass build parameter to configure

Tags: configure

It appears that passing the preferred compiler to configure is very different for different projects. For example, if I want to build tcc with clang I must do `./configure --cc=clang` but in most other cases a project would understand the `./configure CC=clang`. Is there even a de facto standard or does it not matter and I should check for each individual project which way it is done?

```
  $ wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/tcc/0.9.27\+git20200814.62c30a4a-1/tcc_0.9.27\+git20200814.62c30a4a.orig.tar.bz2
  $ tar -xvjf tcc_0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a.orig.tar.bz2
  $ ./configure --cc=clang
  $ make
  $ make install
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases, `configure` scripts are generated by Autoconf, and [the recommendation is to set variables in arguments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/654153/86440):

```
./configure CC=clang
```

However, some projects (such as `tcc`) ship a hand-written `configure` script, and practices vary.

As a rule of thumb, if there’s a `configure.ac` file, you can assume the Autoconf behaviour; if there isn’t, you need to check the project’s expectations.

(Strictly speaking, Autoconf-generated scripts don’t *have* to support `CC`, and you should check for the use of [`AC_PROG_CC`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.71/html_node/C-Compiler.html); but the vast majority of Autoconf scripts using a C compiler do.)